# is define code: vector<int> intVector will call default constructor and is same with vector<int> intVector()?

Tags: c++

code one:

```
vector<int> *intVector=new vector<int>();
```

code two:

```
vector<int> *intVector=new vector<int>;
```

code three:

```
vector<int> intVector();//compile error?
```

code four:

```
vector<int> intVector;
```

my questions:

(1) is "vector intVector"  call default constructor?
(2) when code 1 is similar with code 2,  why code 3 compiled error?

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. `vector<int> intVector();` declares a function.

Comment: @soon: Comments are not for short answers.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'm not sure if I should make it as answer or not. This question is **very** popular and it has been asked many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> (1) is "vector intVector" call default constructor?
>   (2) when code 1 is similar with code 2, why code 3 compiled error?

Regarding (1), yes, `std::vector` has a user-defined default constructor, which is used when no constructor arguments are provided.

Regarding (2), your code 3 shouldn't give an error of itself, but it is a declaration of a function, not a declaration of a variable. So if you're using it as a variable, then you may get compilation errors on that usage.

Your code example 4 is how you should generally use a `std::vector`. For a number of reasons there is little to no point in allocating a `std::vector` dynamically, with `new`, and there is a (relatively speaking) huge cost associated with `new`. So just use a straight `std::vector` object, and it takes care of memory allocation and deallocation for you.